# Heroku and Beautiful Soup

Tags: heroku, import, dependencies, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble with the beautifulsoup module dependency for heroku.

I followed the steps for specifying dependence here

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#specify-dependencies-with-pip

But I keep getting the error "ImportError: No module named bs4"
when it reaches this line "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup "

But the requirements.txt file has the following

```
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
```

Also i did start from fresh and try to make a new app, that didn't work.
These errors on the heroku servers, running the app locally gives me no problem.

Comment: Is `requirements.txt` in the root of your repository?

Comment: meaning that it the one of the first files in the app folder?  yes

Comment: That depends on what you mean by the “app folder”. What does `ls -d .git requirements.txt` show?

Comment: .git  requirements.txt === Thats what is shows

Comment: What does your `Procfile` contain?

Comment: studybugger: python Main.py

Comment: What does `git status` show?

Comment: On branch master === nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: @minitech thanks for the help, I learned some useful commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the PhantomJS buildpack.

However, that mean heroku was no longer detecting the python buildpack and thus not importing beautifulsoup.

To fix the problem, I exected this command in terminal

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

Then I created a text file called ".buildpack" , include the dot at the beginning.
I then pasted these two urls in the text file

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs
```

This tell it to use the python buildpack and the phantomJS buildpack.